# Finding all files with certain extension in Unix?

Tags: macos, unix, search, terminal

I have a file `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

I am trying to find if I have the *.jdk anywhere else on my hard drive. So I do a search command:

```
find . -name "*.jdk"
```

But it doesn't find anything. Not even the one I know that I have. How come?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

`find .` only looks in your current directory. If you have permissions to look for files in other directories (root access) then you can use the following to find your file -

```
find / -type f -name "*.jdk"
```

If you are getting tons of permission denied messages then you can suppress that by doing

```
find / -type f -name "*.jdk" 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: @Prostak, this will only show regular files, not directories. `-type f` is to filter out symbolic links, directories, devices, and such.

Comment: I am marking this one as correct answer. But thanks to both of you for your help!

Comment: How does `2> /dev/null` part work?

Comment: @DanielApt `2>` redirects the error messages to 'somewhere else', while regular output (`1>`) still gets printed to the Terminal.

Answer (score 13):

a/

`find .` means, "find (starting in the current directory)." If you want to search the whole system, use `find /`; to search under `/System/Library`, use `find /System/Library`, etc.

b/

It's safer to use single quotes around wildcards. If there are no files named *.jdk in the working directory when you run this, then `find` will get a command-line of:

```
    find . -name *.jdk
```

If, however, you happen to have files `junk.jdk` and `foo.jdk` in the *current directory* when you run it, `find` will instead be started with:

```
    find . -name junk.jdk foo.jdk
```

… which will (since there are two) confuse it, and cause it to error out. If you then delete `foo.jdk` and do the exact same thing again, you'd have

```
    find . -name junk.jdk
```

…which would never find a file named (e.g.) `1.6.0.jdk`.

What you probably want in this context, is

```
    find /System -name '*.jdk'
```

…or, you can "escape" the `*` as:

```
    find /System -name \*.jdk
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably your JDKs are uppercase and/or the version of `find` available on OS X doesn't default to `-print` if no action is specified; try:

```
find . -iname "*.jdk" -print
```

(`-iname` is like `-name` but performs a case-insensitive match; `-print` says to `find` to print out the results)

--- EDIT ---

As noted by @Jaypal, obviously `find .` ... looks only into the current directory (and subdirectories), if you want to search the whole drive you have to specify `/` as search path.

Comment: Why you have to use `-print`, isn't the default?

Comment: @giannischristofakis: just checked the POSIX standard, yes, it's the default; probably I wrote it explicitly because I feared it was a GNUism I was used to (for example, in GNU find you can also leave out the `.`, while IIRC in BSD find it's required).

Answer (score 4):

The '.' you are using is the current directory. If you're starting in your home dir, it will probably miss the JDK files.

Worst case search is to start from root

```
 find / -name '*.jdk' -o -name '*.JDK' -print
```

Otherwise replace '/' with some path you are certain should be parent to you JDK files.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac terminal, and also already in the directory where you want the search to be conducted at, then this may also work for you:

```
find *.pdf
```

At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

find / -type f -name "*.jdk" works on Mac also

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on macOS.

```sh
find . -type f -iname '*.jdk'
```

Answer (score 0):

ls *.jpg | cut -f 1 -d "."

sub out the '.jpg' to whatever extension you want to list

Comment: What if the files are in a subdirectory?